# AttributeError: module 'spacy' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, attributes, load, attributeerror, spacy-3

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

**Error:** Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\PavanKumar\.spyder-py3\ExcelML.py", line 27, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

AttributeError: module 'spacy' has no attribute 'load'
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Do you have a file named `spacy.py` in your directory? If so you should change the name, that might cause this issue.

Answer (score 32):

Don't name the file spacy.py, it will create conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing spacy again, I had the same problem, after running `conda install spacy` and restarting my notebook kernel it worked.
For the complete installation documentation check the spacy official website: [spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out the error was caused by naming the file 'spacy', apparently it creates a naming conflict. In Python distinctive files are modules, and therefore by naming it 'spacy', you overwrite the file and import itself. Consequently, you should not name your files with package names and they will work well. Once I renamed the file into something else, it worked flawlessly. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem and it was because I named the file spacy.py which created a conflict

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35369340)