# Where to find spacy.py file to rename

Tags: python, terminal, nlp, spacy

I am attempting to install [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/) and have tried a number of methods using `pip`, `conda`, and installing directing from git. However, I am running into the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 3
      1 import spacy
----> 3 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

AttributeError: module 'spacy' has no attribute 'load'
```

From reading various articles online like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769003/attributeerror-module-spacy-has-no-attribute-load), I see that my error is likely due to a file called "spacy.py" that is causing a shadowing error. However, I can't find this file. I feel like this is likely an easy thing to find but have yet to find it :(

Using `which python` in my dir shows me:

```
/Users/my_name/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Looking into my anaconda3/bin/python dir, I do see a Unix Executable file named "spacy" but renaming it has not fixed my error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve a module's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path)

Comment: You can do this with something like `import spacy; print(spacy.__file__)`. That will give you the path Python is loading the module from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're also installing your preferred package:

For pip:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Also, if you're using a virtual environment in your IDE, you should also run the following commands BEFORE installing spacy and your preferred package:

For pip:

```
python -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
```

For conda:

```
conda create -n venv
conda activate venv
```

There could also be a [mismatch](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2306) between your environments. If you're using Anaconda, try installing spacy in the Anaconda Powershell. Otherwise, try installing spacy using conda and/or pip in your IDE's terminal.